# i want my program not printing all digits with numbers and not start or end or duplicate with (.)

Tags: java, arrays

this program printing combination of 4 digests I want to put some condition to prevent printing all digest with the number and also shouldn't digest start or end or duplicated with the symbol (.)

```
public class Comb{

  public Comb(){
    String str_arr[]={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9",".","_"};
    GenCombinations(str_arr);
  }

  public void GenCombinations(String[] str_arr){
    System.out.println("Generating All possible Combinations for  the following "+str_arr.length+" strings.");        

    for (String str_arr1 : str_arr) {
      System.out.print(str_arr1 + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("\n"
        + "");

      for (String str_arr3 : str_arr) {
        for (String str_arr2 : str_arr) {
          for (String str_arr1 : str_arr) {
              for (String str_arr4 : str_arr) {
                  System.out.println(str_arr3 + "" + str_arr2 + "" + str_arr1 + "" + str_arr4);
              }
          }
        }
      }
  } 

  public static void main(String[] args){  
    new Comb();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share your desired (or example) output.

Comment: digits, numbers, digest, please clarify what you mean and what your problem is with your current code.

Comment: this program printing possible username I just want to put conditions to avoid printing all digest with numbers like (9976) or start or end or duplicate (.) like (.fg5) or (fg5.) or (f..6) this is what i mean

Comment: @salim Please add this information to the question instead.

Answer (score -2):

Could you try this;

```
String kulaniciIsmi = str_arr3 + str_arr2 + str_arr1 + str_arr4;
if (!kulaniciIsmi.matches("(^[0-9.].*)|(.*[0-9.]$)|(^*.[.]{2}.*$)")) {
       System.out.println(kulaniciIsmi);
}
```

This `(^[0-9.].*)` prevents start with digit or . char;

This `(.*[0-9.]$)` prevents end with digit or . char;

This `(^*.[.]{2}.*$)` prevents ".." chars in the middle;

Comment: its work but only that it doesn't print digest with (.) anymore I want it to print the (.) but shouldn't be at the end or beginning or duplicate in  digest

Comment: You have 4 for loops inside each other then 5 `if` conditions making the code almost unreadable

Comment: This code reminds me of de-compiled code from a source! :P I think we can do better than machines;)